# How can WinForm host a long run IronPython script, and update UI for progress change

Tags: c#, python, winforms, user-interface, no-response

I need a WinForm act as the IronPython host, and during the IronPython run-time, the script can update UI to report its progress. I have the following code, and it does update the UI, but the problem is that the Window is not responsive. I appreciate any help.

```
namespace TryAsyncReport
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //use python
        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IProgress<ProgressReportInfo> progress = new Progress<ProgressReportInfo>(ReportProgress);
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
                ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
                string script = "for i in range(1000000):\r\n";
                script += "   progress.Report(ProgressReportInfo(i / 10000, str(i / 10000)));\r\n";
                scope.SetVariable("progress", progress);
                scope.SetVariable("ProgressReportInfo", typeof(ProgressReportInfo));
                var code = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(script);
                code.Execute(scope);

            });

        }

        private void ReportProgress(ProgressReportInfo info)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = info.Percentage; 
            label1.Text = info.Status; 
        }

    }

    public class ProgressReportInfo
    {
        public ProgressReportInfo(int percentage, string status)
        {
            Percentage = percentage;
            Status = status;
        }
        public int Percentage { set; get; }
        public string Status { set; get; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `Invoke` to UI thread:

```
    private void ReportProgress(ProgressReportInfo info)
    {
        // or better BeginInvoke
        Invoke(() =>
        {
            progressBar1.Value = info.Percentage;
            label1.Text = info.Status;
        });
    }
```

and you don't need to `await` for `Task.Run`.

Also, consider do not report every bit of progress change, but let say every 1000 changes.

Other solution is to use *polling watcher* (your script change value of `volatile` variable, this value is checked in the timer)

Comment: Thank you Sinatr. However the GUI is still not responsive when Python is running.

Comment: Try running long python script in separate thread without passing/calling anything from/into. This shouldn't block UI. If it does, then something is wrong with python `Execute`. Perhaps there is a property to (guess) run with blocking/not blocking of calling process?

Comment: The problem is induced since Python updates the UI. If the the "progress.Report(...)" is replaced by "i++", the issue is gone. As your suggested, I looked around for possible property for "Execute", but no result. Actually I also tried a BackgroundWork, it shows the same behavior.

Comment: How do you update UI from within python code? I see now (lol), you are not calling `ReportProgress` there, but calling `Report` method. Show please `Report` method code, the problem is there.

Comment: progress.Report actually calls this function "private void ReportProgress(ProgressReportInfo info)"

Comment: Then I correctly suggested you to use `Invoke` in `ReportProgress()`. Though I am not sure now, but simply use `BeginInvoke` (maybe you call `Invoke` way too often, which should not completely block UI, but may feels this way).

Comment: I retried your advice "Also, consider do not report every bit of progress change, but let say every 1000 changes.". And it's true, if I reduce the frequency, the UI is not blocked. So I should ask my users, Python script writers, not to report back the progress too often. And actually doesn't need Invoke or BeginInvoke. Thank you so much!